# Path title show in Hover with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want how to svg path title show with hover?

```
        $( "path" ).click(function() {
            $("#country").val($(this).attr('title'));
            $( "#target" ).submit();
        });
```

**Some SVG code:**

```
<path id="IE-CW" title="Carlow" class="land" d="M458.79,501.13L460.38,501.38L461.8,500.65L463.58,502.11L463.79,502.83L464.9L457.76,504.49L457.53,501.71L458.46,501.86z"/>
```

Comment: please share your svg code to

Comment: please add some more code like html and describe a bit more what actually want and where you stuck?

Comment: svg code has added

Answer (score 0):

```
Instead of using title attribute, use a nested title element. 
Use the below code:
<path id="IE-CW" title="Carlow" class="land" d="M458.79,501.13L460.38,501.38L461.8,500.65L463.58,502.11L463.79,502.83L464.9L457.76,504.49L457.53,501.71L458.46,501.86z">
 <title>Carlow</title> 
</path>
```